# Leibniz rule for dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

At [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Dot_product_rule) it is stated under "dot product rule" that for $\mathbf{A,B}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ smooth vector fields, it holds

$$ \nabla \langle \mathbf{A,B} \rangle =\mathbf{A \cdot J_B + B \cdot J_A} $$

where $\mathbf{J}$ is the jacobian matrix.

But on the righthand side of the equation I get "vector $\times$ squared matrix", which is not a valid row-column product. Is the formula formally wrong? Is the following formula correct?

$$ \nabla \langle \mathbf{A,B} \rangle = \mathbf{J_B \cdot A  + J_A \cdot B} $$

Is there a reason they wrote it the other way around? (e.g.: further generalizations in manifolds...)?

Comment: Just because they write vectors as row vectors instead of column ones.

Comment: Ok, cause I've never seen doing this. So I should just switch the terms in the dot products... Thanks